# Dynamic IP address in /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, server, dns

Is there a way to use dynamic ip address for a custom domain in `/etc/hosts` file?
Or, maybe, use a environment variable for the IP like this:

```
IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
IP    mycustomdomain.com
```

The IP for this machine changes everyday and everyday I need to edit this file so I can access a web server with its custom development domain. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: If this is a server you control, maybe it's better some dynamic DNS solution on the server side?

Comment: There's no way to do this in `/etc/hosts` no.  It also doesn't inherit env vars.  If you need this type of setup you need to set up a Dynamic DNS solution not an /etc/hosts solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll search Dynamic DNS solutions! Thanks!